# Trying to update an excel table using a multiselect form

Tags: excel, vba, multi-select

I'm creating a simple log that will update a table of devices to show when the last firmware update was and who updated it. I have a form that will update a single device entry correctly, but I can't get it to work with multiselect. It will only update the last item in the list.

How can I get it so that a that someone can update multiple entries with their name and date in a single use of the form? I think I need to loop through the selected index values (for loop?), but I'm just not seeing it.

```
    Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()
    EditIndex = Me.UpdateDevice.ListIndex

    If EditIndex = -1 Then
      MsgBox "No device was selected", vbExclamation, "Update Log"

    Else
       EditIndex = EditIndex + 2
       Devices.Range("F" & EditIndex) = Me.DateUpdated
       Devices.Range("G" & EditIndex) = Me.UpdatedBy

       Unload Me

   End If

   MsgBox "Log has been successfully updated", vbExclamation, "Update Log"

   End Sub
```

EditIndex is a public variable I have saved in a module to use across various forms in this file.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()
EditIndex = Me.UpdateDevice.ListIndex
Dim i As Integer
Dim rmaster As Long


If EditIndex = -1 Then
   MsgBox "No device was selected", vbExclamation, "Update Log"
   Exit Sub

Else
   For i = 0 To Me.UpdateDevice.ListCount - 1
      If Me.UpdateDevice.Selected(i) Then
        rmaster = i + 2
        Devices.Range("F" & rmaster) = Me.DateUpdated.Value
        Devices.Range("G" & rmaster) = Me.UpdatedBy.Value
        Debug.Print (Me.UpdateDevice.List(i))
        Debug.Print rmaster
      Else
        
      End If
  Next i

Unload Me

End If

MsgBox "Log has been successfully updated", vbExclamation, "Update Log"

End Sub
```

I kept the debug.print to see if it was returning correctly. Only returns the first selected item if I try to update the columns.

Answer (score 0):

The `.ListIndex` property only returns the index of the last selected item from a multiselect enabled listbox control.  You'll have to iterate though all the items in the list and check to see if they have been selected.  Note that `.ListCount` returns the number of items in the listbox control starting with 1 while the `.Selected(i)` references the list index values which start at 0.  (i.e. if the listbox has one item in it, `.ListCount` returns 1 while `.ListIndex` returns 0 because there is 1 item in the list, but it is the item at the 0th index).

```
For i = 0 To Me.lsBox.ListCount - 1
    If Me.lsBox.Selected(i) Then
        'record was selected
        'do something
        Debug.Print (Me.lsBox.List(i))
    Else
        'record was not selected
        'do nothing
    End If
Next i
```

**Edit 1 - In action**

[image]

**Edit 2 - OPs updated code exactly**

[image]

Comment: The loop works correctly to identify each entry selected and I got it to return the correct row in the table. But as soon as I turn in the code to add info to columns, it only returns the first item and ignores the rest.

Comment: I posted the code I used based off your answer above. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @brettrussell I'm not seeing any errors in what you provided in your answer.  Can you update your answer with the complete code?  Maybe there is something else outside of the loop that is causing this behavior.

Comment: @brettrussell I modified my demo to use your code exactly and everything seems to work on my end.  Is the behavior in edit 2 of my answer what you are expecting?

Comment: That's exactly what it should do! But I can only ever get 1 item to update. I don't know what to do.

Comment: @brettrussell the only other thing is to step through the execution line by line to isolate the issue.  If there is no issue there, it could be something with the other code in the workbook interfering some way, or an odd property setting in the form or something.

Comment: I'm just glad my code works somewhere. Thanks for the help. I'll start looking through that procedure and others tomorrow as I have time.

Comment: Ok, the For loop iterates through all of the selected entries, I can see the i variable updating with each iteration. The If nested inside will recognize the first .Selected(i), updates the rmaster variable and writes to the correct columns in the table. The very next i is not recognized as selected, so it jumps to the Else to evaluate the next i. Any i selected after the first one is skipped over like it isn't selected. Like the selection was cleared after the first one.

Comment: @brettrussell That's strange, I don't know what would be causing that behavior.  The only think I can think is the multiselect setting on the listbox, I used the regular multiselect, not the extended.  If that doesn't resolve it, you can try putting the code in a sperate workbook to see if it works there.  Other than that, I'm not sure.

Comment: I tried both multiselect settings, same problem with either one. I did try to replicate everything in another workbook. I started with other procedures for adding and deleting records to the table. Those worked fine at first, but ran into trouble either after I added the update procedure you helped me with or just after I ran them the first time. I haven't had time to go through it again, but I think the bug is related to the other procedures.

Answer (score 0):

### ListBox to Update Worksheet

- `ListIndex` will return `-1` only if the list box is empty (not populated).

**Objects**

```
 Command Button - UpdateButton
 List Box       - UpdateDevice
 Text Box       - DateUpdated
 Text Box       - UpdatedBy
 Worksheet      - Devices
```

- All controls are on a user form.
- `Devices` is the **code name** of the worksheet.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()
    
    Dim ItemsCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    With Me.UpdateDevice
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                ItemsCount = ItemsCount + 1
                EditIndex = i + 2 ' EditIndex is maybe not needed!?
                Devices.Range("F" & EditIndex) = Me.DateUpdated
                Devices.Range("G" & EditIndex) = Me.UpdatedBy
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    ' I don't know why, but I needed the following line to see the complete
    ' change in worksheet 'Devices' (CodeName) before the MsgBox:
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Select Case ItemsCount
        Case 0
        MsgBox "No device was selected", vbExclamation, "Update Log"
        Case 1
        MsgBox "Log has been successfully updated with 1" _
             & " entry.", vbInformation, "Update Log"
        Case Else
        MsgBox "Log has been successfully updated with " & ItemsCount _
             & " entries.", vbInformation, "Update Log"
    End Select
    Unload Me
    
End Sub
```